# Serverless + next.js with basic auth and ip whitelist

Tags: aws-lambda, next.js, serverless, aws-serverless

I've been struggling with the following problem: how to configure serverless with IP whitelist authorizing and fallback to BasicAuth (to root path) if IP doesn't match to whitelist?

It's quite easy to add IP whitelist authorizing (https://github.com/0is1/nextjs-serverless-test/blob/master/serverless.yml#L23-L34). And it's also quite easy to add BasicAuth (or any Authorizer in general) like https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#http-endpoints-with-custom-authorizers. But how to combine those two with serverless + AWS Cloud​Formation configs?

It seems that if `serverless-nextjs-plugin` is used it's not possible to use serverless config like:

```
functions:
   handler:
     handler: handler
     events:
       - http:
           path: / # Add basic auth to root
           method: GET
           authorizer: ${self:custom.authorizer.users} # this is doing nothing if serverless-nextjs-plugin is on
```

Or it's possible but it doesn't do anything.

I've created test repo about the progress so far https://github.com/0is1/nextjs-serverless-test

To recap:

1. How to combine IP whitelist and fallback to another Authorizer if ip doesn't match to whitelist with serverless
2. How to add BasicAuth to app root if `serverless-nextjs-plugin` is used

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you managed to figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: Yep, any luck here either. Guess i will have to to through the link through the deploy pipeline.